# Default value in prometheus field

Tags: prometheus

i have some exporters that are setup for live and staging environments... and i want to use metric_relabel_configs to add the environment field in prometheus for those metrics. The live hostname are in the format `live-something`, but most staging do not, only have `something`.

Is there any way to get the `live` value from the hostname and if it fails, fallback to a default value, `staging` ?

i already tried this, but didn't worked, i always get staging:

```
 -  target_label: environment
    replacement: staging
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: .*(live|staging).*
    target_label: environment
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, however `__address__` isn't available in metric relabelling. This is a target label, so use `relabel_configs`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed most problems... but node_exporter still a problem, node_exporter metrics do not have the nodename, only node_uname_info have it...probably on this one special case i need to use metric_relabel instead... correct, it worked! :D